# Java Index Does Not Exist In ArrayList<Double>

Tags: java, indexing

I currently have an ArrayList which houses the first 1000 prime numbers.  I am able to successfully print the list to the console.

I am then applying the following method:

```
public static ScalesSolution RMHC(ArrayList<Double> weights, int n, int iter){

    private String scasol;

    ScalesSolution sol = new ScalesSolution(n);

    for(int i = 1; i <= iter; i++){

        double oldsol = sol.ScalesFitness(weights);

        sol.smallChange(n);
        sol.println();

        double newsol = sol.ScalesFitness(weights);

        if(newsol > oldsol){
            newsol = oldsol;
        }
    }
    return(sol);
}
```

Main method:

```
public static void main(String[] args){

    ArrayList<Double> primes = new ArrayList<Double>();

    primes.addAll(CS2004.ReadNumberFile("1000 Primes.txt"));

    RMHC(primes, 10, 50);

}
```

ScalesSolution class:

```
public class ScalesSolution{

public void smallChange(int n)
{
    Random rand = new Random();
    int p = (rand.nextInt(n) - 1);

    //Checks if p < 0.  If so, then p will not have 1 subtracted from it.
    if(p < 0){
        p = (rand.nextInt(n));
    }

    String x = new String();

    x = scasol.substring(0, p);

        if (scasol.charAt(p) == '0')
            scasol.replace('0', '1');
        else if (scasol.charAt(p) == '1')
            scasol.replace('1', '0');
            scasol = x;
}//End smallChange()

}
```

Whenever I call the method, however, I receive the following error no matter what I enter for the parameters.  (FYI, `ArrayList<Double> weights` is the list of primes, `int n` is the size of the solution to look for and `iter` is the number of iterations that the algorithm will run for.)

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 6
at java.lang.String.substring(Unknown Source)
at ScalesSolution.smallChange(ScalesSolution.java:90)
at Lab8.RMHC(Lab8.java:15)
at Lab8.main(Lab8.java:46)
```

As mentioned above, the list contains 1000 elements (1000 - 1 indices), however I always receive the error above.

As you can see, it points to an error at index position 6, but there are `1000 - 1` index positions, so why does this happen?  The index position changes with each run, but each and every time I run it, the error arises.

Thank you.

Comment: show us where is scasol declaration

Comment: It's worth noting that your `scasol.replace()` methods aren't doing anything, since they return a new string which you aren't doing anything with. Also, your indentation suggests you believe the `scasol = x` line is part of the else block, but it isn't. Best practice here is to always uses braces, even when they're optional.

Comment: @dty Thank you for your comment.  I see what you mean - I too suspected that the `scasol.replace()` methods weren't doing anything but I was not sure how to go about it.  What I am aiming to do is to make a small change (hence the method name) to a `String` variable so that when a `1` is encountered, it is changed to a `0` and vice versa.  May I ask what you would recommend?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is on this line:

```
x = scasol.substring(0, p);
```

The value of p (6) that you are passing in to the substring method is too large for the string scasol.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting an exception because `p` is not a valid index for the String `scasol`. Can you print out that String and check its value? Is it the expected value? Also, no need to do `new String()` as strings in Java are immutable.

Answer (score 0):

This line:

```
at ScalesSolution.smallChange(ScalesSolution.java:90)
```

point you that in 90 line in ScalesSolution you have Exception, so try before this line call System.out.println with scasol and p value, then you'll see what cause the problem

Answer (score 0):

In addition to GregInYEG's answer, you can apply modulus on p to avoid this problem like this: `int p = (rand.nextInt(n) - 1) % scasol.length();`

Answer (score 0):

It may be that the issue occurs because you shorted scasol on each call of smallChange.

The lines

```
String x = new String();
x = scasol.substring(0, p);

if (scasol.charAt(p) == '0')
    scasol.replace('0', '1');
else if (scasol.charAt(p) == '1')
    scasol.replace('1', '0');

scasol = x;
```

are functionally equivalent to

```
scasol = scasol.substring(0, p);
```

and thus cut your string scasol is shortened to `p` chars and may not be long enough for the second call within your for loop.

I think these lines should actually do something different? Can you please describe what the expected function of this method should be?

Also the lines

```
Random rand = new Random();
int p = (rand.nextInt(n) - 1);

//Checks if p < 0.  If so, then p will not have 1 subtracted from it.
if(p < 0){
    p = (rand.nextInt(n));
}
```

look strange. What do you want to accomplish here? What it does is get a random number between 0 and n-1 while n-1 is much more seldom than any other value.